# How to get the date from the given string in c#

Tags: c#, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting, date-conversion

I only need date from this string **Wed, 02/05/2020 - 12:31** what format should I use whenever I am using
{MM/dd/yyyy} I am getting the same value if there is any other way please let me know

```
        item.changed=Wed, 02/05/2020 - 12:31


    `if (ListRecord.checkresponse == "Response Letters")
                {
                
                string checkresponse = item.changed;
                string issueDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", checkresponse);

                 }`
```

Comment: just follow [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use date formatting, you need to start with a `DateTime` object, not a string.

So in your scenario you'll have to parse your string as a DateTime, then format it out again to a different string format. There's no way to directly format string -> string, all the logic about formatting is in the DateTime class.

Here's an example:

```
string changed = "Wed, 02/05/2020 - 12:31";
var checkresponse = DateTime.ParseExact(changed, "ddd, MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string issueDate = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", checkresponse);
Console.WriteLine(issueDate);
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bhNImo

(Alternatively, since what you mainly want to do here is strip the first and last parts of the string and keep the date part, you *could* use a regular expression do to this from the string, but overall it's probably more reliably to use date parsing and formatting.)